# setEmptyView for ListView created from AlertDialog

Tags: android, listview, dialog, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to use the `setEmptyView()` method for a `ListView` that has been created via the `AlertDialog` `builder` method. Since the `ListView` is created by the `builder`, I figured I should be able to inflate a view, e.g., `my_empty_view.xml`, and get an instance of the dialog's `ListView` and set the empty view accordingly, i.e.,

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);    
View myEmptyView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_empty_view.xml, null);

// Alert Dialog Code Here
dialog = builder.create();
ListView listView = dialog.getListView();
listView.setEmptyView(myEmptyView);
```

Whilst this doesn't throw any errors, it doesn't give the empty view when the Adapter is empty. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

So I'm not sure that it is possible to set `SetEmptyView` after the adapter has been set in the `AlertDialog` builder using the builder's `setAdapter` method.

However, I worked around this by defining a `ListView` and my empty view (e.g. `TextView` with visibility set to gone) in the same xml file, e.g.,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/my_list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_empty_view"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Searching for devices..."
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:paddingTop="50dp"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

I inflated this view group in the `OnCreateDialog` method of my extended `DialogFragment` class (as described in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) under **Creating a Custom Layout**), i.e.,

```
View myDialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog_view, null);
```

retrieved references to my `ListView` and empty view from the inflated view, i.e.,

```
ListView myListView = (ListView) myDialogView.findViewById(R.id.my_list_view);
TextView myEmptyView = (TextView) myDialogView.findViewById(R.id.my_empty_view);
```

set the list view `setemptyView` using these, i.e.,

```
myListView.setEmptyView(myEmptyView);
```

set my adapter

```
myListView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
```

and then in the builder simply used the `setView()` method

```
.setView(myDialogView)
```

This is probably the best way. I was thrown by the android documentation where it suggests using the `setAdapter` method in the `AlertDialog` builder. Personally, I think sticking to the `setView` method offers more flexibility.